# Generate event in android when more than one condition is met

Tags: java, android

I have two text boxes and a seek arc in my activity. The button should be activated only when these conditions specified below are satisfied.

- The text boxes should have some content.
- The seek arc should be set to a specific value.

How to implement this condition in my application. I've tried the observer pattern but it applies to one subject and many listeners. How to create an event which is triggered when these three conditions are satisfied?

Comment: You could have three different booleans for each element where true means that it has met your condition. Every time you change one of the booleans call a function that checks the values and then trigger event if all are true.

Comment: @ Glenn Werner Thanks....that works

Comment: No problem. Good luck

Comment: @Glenn Werner but is using too many flags a bad practice..?? Is there any other work around?

Comment: I guess you could have a runnable that calls a function every second where the function would make sure there was content in the text boxes and the seek arc was in the right spot. If so then it would start the event. As far as having a lot of flags...I think most of the time if you have a lot that means you should probably restructure your code. But there are some instances when it would be fine IMO.